# After two mov in memory register system crash

Tags: gcc, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, inline-assembly

I'm trying to perform some write in memory registers from user space ( through a custom driver ). I want to write three 64-bit integer and I initialized the variables "value_1, value_2 and value_3" to uint64_t type.

I must use the gcc inline mov instruction and I'm working on an ARM 64-bit architecture on a custom version of linux for an embedded system.

Thi is my code:

```
  asm ( "MOV %[reg1], %[val1]\t\n"
        "MOV %[reg2], %[val2]\t\n"
        "MOV %[reg3], %[val3]\t\n"

        :[reg1] "=&r" (*register_1),[arg2] "=&r" (*register_2), [arg3] "=&r" (*register_3)
        :[val1] "r"(value_1),[val2] "r" (value_2), [val3] "r" (value_3)
     );
```

The problem is strange...
If I perform just two MOV, the code works. 
If I perform all the three MOV, the entire system crash and I have to reboot the entire system.

even stranger...
If I put a "printf" o even a nanosleep with 0 nanosecond between the second and the third MOV, the code works!

I looked around trying to find a solution and I also use the clobber of the memory:

```
asm ( "MOV %[reg1], %[val1]\t\n"
      "MOV %[reg2], %[val2]\t\n"
      "MOV %[reg3], %[val3]\t\n"

      :[reg1] "=&r" (*register_1),[arg2] "=&r" (*register_2), [arg3] "=&r" (*register_3)
      :[val1] "r"(value_1),[val2] "r" (value_2), [val3] "r" (value_3)
      :"memory"
   );
```

...doen't work!

I used also the memory barrier macro between the second and the third MOV or at the end of the three MOV:

```
asm volatile("": : :"memory")
```

..doesn't work!

Also, I tried to write directly into the register using pointers and I had the same behavior: after the second write the system crash...

Anybody can suggest me a solution..or tell me if I'm using the gcc inline MOV or the memory barrier in a wrong way?

----> MORE DETAILS <-----

This is my main:

```
int main() 
{ 
    int  dev_fd;
    volatile void * base_addr = NULL;
    volatile uint64_t * reg1_addr = NULL;

    volatile uint32_t * reg2_addr = NULL;

    volatile uint32_t * reg3_addr = NULL;

    dev_fd = open(MY_DEVICE, O_RDWR);
    if (dev_fd < 0)
    {
            perror("Open call failed");
            return -1;
    }

    base_addr = mmap(NULL, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, xsmll_dev_fd, 0);
    if (base_addr == MAP_FAILED)
    {
            perror("mmap operation failed");
            return -1;
    }
    printf("BASE ADDRESS VIRT: 0x%p\n", base_addr);

    /* Preparing the registers */
    reg1_addr = base_addr + REG1_OFF;
    reg2_addr = base_addr + REG2_OFF;
    reg3_addr = base_addr + REG3_OFF;

     uint64_t val_1 = 0xEEEEEEEE;
    uint64_t val_2 = 0x00030010;
    uint64_t val_3 = 0x01;

    asm ( "str %[val1], %[reg1]\t\n"
          "str %[val2], %[reg2]\t\n"
          "str %[val3], %[reg3]\t\n"

      :[reg1] "=&m" (*reg1_addr),[reg2] "=&m" (*reg2_addr), [reg3] "=&m" (*reg3_addr)
      :[val1] "r"(val_1),[val2] "r" (val_2), [val3] "r" (val_3)
      );

    printf("--- END ---\n");
    close(dev_fd);
    return 0;
  }
```

This is the output of the compiler regarding the asm statement (linaro..I cross compile):

```
  400bfc:       f90013a0        str     x0, [x29,#32]
  400c00:       f94027a3        ldr     x3, [x29,#72]
  400c04:       f94023a4        ldr     x4, [x29,#64]
  400c08:       f9402ba5        ldr     x5, [x29,#80]
  400c0c:       f9401ba0        ldr     x0, [x29,#48]
  400c10:       f94017a1        ldr     x1, [x29,#40]
  400c14:       f94013a2        ldr     x2, [x29,#32]
  400c18:       f9000060        str     x0, [x3]
  400c1c:       f9000081        str     x1, [x4]
  400c20:       f90000a2        str     x2, [x5]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Oh, you should use `asm volatile`, because you need it to not optimize away when you compile normally (with `-O2` or `-O3`) instead of a debug build.  Other than that, IDK, looks like your asm is doing what you specified, so single-step it with a debugger, and/or debug whatever kernel driver is backing that device file you mmap.

Comment: It looks like you don't need inline asm for this; the compiler will emit those `str` instructions for you if you just `*reg1_addr = val_1;` and so on.

Comment: asm volatile doesn't solve the problem...

I will try to use the GDB...

Really thank you for your help

Comment: I tried with *reg1_addr = val_1; and I have the same problem...

Comment: Then this code isn't the problem.  Avoiding `asm` is just a cleaner way to get equivalent machine code, without having to use inline asm.  Your problem is probably your choice of registers and values, or the kernel driver.  (Or do you need the values to be in CPU registers before writing the first mmaped location, to avoid loading anything from the stack between stores?  That's the only reason you'd need inline asm)

Comment: I need just to write values in registers, mapped by a kernel driver, from user space. Without jump in kernel space. These registers will be read by an FPGA FSM

Comment: Then you don't need inline asm, and pure C with `volatile` should be equivalent to your fixed inline asm.  If that still doesn't work, the problem isn't how you're writing registers, it's something else, perhaps *which* MMIO registers you're writing, the values you're writing to them, or something wrong with the memory mapping.

Comment: yes...probably the problem is into the kernel driver...

Answer (score 2):

> I tried with *reg1_addr = val_1; and I have the same problem.

Then this code isn't the problem. Avoiding `asm` is just a cleaner way to get equivalent machine code, without having to use inline asm. Your problem is more likely your choice of registers and values, or the kernel driver.

Or do you need the values to be in CPU registers before writing the first mmaped location, to avoid loading anything from the stack between stores? That's the only reason I can think of that you'd need inline asm, where compiler-generated stores might not be equivalent.

---

**Answer to original question**:

An `"=&r"` output constraint means a *CPU* register.  So your inline-asm instructions will run in that order, assembling to something like

```
mov x0, x5
mov x1, x6
mov x2, x7
```

And then after that, compiler-generated code will store the values back to memory in some unspecified order.  That order depends on how it chooses to generate code for the surrounding C.   This is probably why changing the surrounding code changes the behaviour.

One solution might be `"=&m"` constraints with `str` instructions, so your asm *does* actually store to memory.  `str %[val1], %[reg1]` because STR instructions take the addressing mode as the 2nd operand, even though it's the destination.

---

Why can't you use `volatile uint64_t* = register_1;` like a normal person, to have the compiler emit store instructions that it's not allowed to reorder or optimize away?  MMIO is exactly what `volatile` is for.

Doesn't Linux have macros or functions for doing MMIO loads/stores?

---

If you're having problem with inline asm, step 1 in debugging should be to look at the actual asm emitted by the compiler when it filled in the asm template, and the surrounding code.

Then single-step by instructions through the code (with GDB `stepi`, maybe in `layout reg` mode).

Comment: I modified my code with str, but the problem remains...

I defined the registers with volatile uint64_t * and also I tried to write directly with poiters, but it didn't solve the problem...

Comment: @colbacc8: then show enough code to make a [mcve], including definitions, and your compiler's asm output.

Comment: @colbacc8: edit your question with your code.  You can't do format large blocks of code in comments, and it belongs in the question anyway.

Comment: sorry...I added more details in the question.. ( I made also a lot of confusion...answering my question...I click on the button to delete it)